# Validation + Regex for Url

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex that accept urls with below combination:

Rules is like below:
1) Should never allow - http or http:// or https or https://
2) www is optional
3) Total length of the url should be <= 20 chars

```
Given few possible sample text and its return value:   
https://sample.com   **-  false**   
https://www.sample.com   **- false**  
www.sample.com   **- true**  
sample123.com   **- true**  
2323sample.com   **- true**  
www.sample232.com   **- true**  
sample.co.uk   **- true**  
sample   **- false**  
.com   **- false**  
123445   **- false**
```

Comment: Are you interested in _valid_ TLDs or are you OK with any TLD being considered valid?

Comment: @vlaz - I am okay with any TLD.

Comment: Your third condition doesn't seem nice .. there are lots of urls That have been made of more than 20 characters.

Comment: @Shafizadeh - Mostly they will have only domainname.com                  or domainname.org, so they made it as <= 20 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^(?!.{21,}|https?:)(?:www\.)?[^.\s@]+\.[^\s]+$/i
```

[See this in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cK0qW1/7)

This is a very light validation! It is deliberately done so to allow non-latin characters because JavaScript regex does not support them.

Explanation:

`(?!.{21,}|https?:)` this is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) that rejects any string longer than 21 characters or if any string string that starts with `http:` or `https:`. Placed in the beginning of the pattern it will immediately reject and not go through the rest of the regex if the string is too long.

`(?:www\.)?` - using a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) to match `www.` and making that an optinal component using the `?` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

`[^.\s@]+` - the pattern should definitely contain at least one symbol that is not a dot or any whitespace character, nor an @ sign. The last one included to prevent less tech savvy users from entering an email instead of a URL (common mistake they can make).

`\.` followed by a literal dot

`[^\s]+` the pattern finishes with at least one non-whitespace character.

`i` - using case-insensitive flag to ensure that URLs like `HTTP://` are not allowed. Although it might be better to convert the URL to lower case, as that will ensure that they are shown uniformly.

As mentioned this is extremely light validation. It will stop users from entering something that is roughly invalid but will not restrict *all* invalid inputs. You can tighten the requirements by modifying what you allow or not allow around in the character groups around the the literal dot character near the end of the pattern. Be warned that there are valid URLs that can be flagged as invalid if you use a character group of the form `[a-z0-9]` - this will *not* allow non-Latin characters, for example Cyrillic or Chinese. JavaScript does not currently support those inside a regular expression - if you need to validate UTF characters, you will need a library like [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) that can handle them.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer. I tested and it looks good except one scenario in my code, but it looks good for same with Regex101. Below is the snippet i have in my code and it fails for sample.com, but it works for ample.com. So if i have word started with S it is failing.

var urlregex = new RegExp("^(?!.{21,}|https?:)(?:www\.)?[^.\s@]+\.[^\s]+$")
return urlregex.test(value);

Comment: If i add like below it works prefect. It's my mistake. 
var urlregex = /^(?!.{21,}|https?:)(?:www\.)?[^.\s@]+\.[^\s]+$/gmi;
return urlregex.test(value);
Thanks for you're awesome regex.